# How to assign a color to each pcd file when viewing multiple files with pcl_viewer from the terminal

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To visualize multiple point clouds concurrently I use

> pcl_viewer file1.pcd file2.pcd

pcl_viewer then assigns random colors to each file but I can not relate which color represents which file. Is it possible to manually assign a color to each pcd file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232484/how-to-assign-a-color-to-each-pcd-file-when-viewing-multiple-files-with-pcl_viewer-from-the-terminal/) by [Abdallah sobehy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26124/abdallah-sobehy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With many trials I noticed that the options specified when using the pcl_viewer command only affects the very next file after it. So, to give different colors for each file simply add the color option with the wanted rgb values before each file as follows:

> pcl_viewer -fc 0,0,255 file1.pcd -fc 0,255,0 file2.pcd

---

Originally posted by [Abdallah sobehy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26124/abdallah-sobehy/) with karma: 33 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1